# Ajective and Adverb grammar

Tags: adverbial-phrases

adjectives followed by  prepositional phrases.Is it adjectives or adverbs 
?
Example: He is afraid of rats.
 She is scared of cats.

Are both "of rats " and "of cats" adverb prepositional phrases?

Comment: Yes, they are PPs, functioning as complement of "afraid" / "scared".

Comment: Thanks.  Are they also functioning as Adverb prepositional phrases of "afraid"/"scared"?

Comment: No, they are complements, not adverbials.

Comment: Thank you very much